# Android: Recording SoundPool output

Tags: android, audio, recording, soundpool

I'm allowing the user to push buttons to play sounds via a SoundPool.  Is it possible to record whatever the SoundPool is playing so that the user can record a sequence of sounds?

Comment: After some poking around it seems that there won't be a way to do this until Google gives us NDK audio support.  Leaving this here in case anyone has the same problem.

Comment: I've also been interested in this.  I wonder if it's possible with the new NDK multimedia API based on the Khronos Group OpenMAX AL? The OpenMAX wiki article says it supports Audio recording.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no possibility to catch played sound. I had the same wish to do this, but for now, it is just possible with record the output of the speaker. For this, You have to use MediaRecorder and record just "live". But I don´t think it is a good solution, there will be much background sounds.