# I need to record and loop soundpool output

Tags: android, media-player, recording, soundpool, audiotrack

The intertubes isn't pulling up much information on this. I have a standard soundpool set up to play various samples. Low latency is essential (for anyone suggesting a different way of doing this)

How can I go about recording what has been played by the soundpool, in order to loop it?

It seems this may not be possible (according to [Android: Recording SoundPool output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269854/android-recording-soundpool-output)) so I will accept any answers which have the same effect but low latency is a must. There will be multiple streams played simultaneously.

Any suggestions?